# Irreducible representation of regular representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, dihedral-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\lambda$ be de left regular representation of $G$ of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e.
$$\lambda_g : h \mapsto gh \text{ for all } h \in G.$$
Specifically, for any function on the group $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ we have
$$(\lambda_g f)(x) = f(g^{-1}x).$$

A representation is said to be reducible if we can write is as
$$D(g) = P^{-1}\lambda_gP,$$
where $D(g)$ is a block diagonal matrix containing irreducible representations, i.e.
$$D(g) = \begin{bmatrix}\rho^1(g) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \rho^2(g) & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \rho^k(g) \end{bmatrix}.$$

How do I find these irreps and $P$ for a given group, let's say the $D_n$ group? Moreover, are these irreps/$P$  unique?

Comment: The regular representation contains each irreducible representation with multiplicity equal to its degree. Does this answer your question or are you looking for something more explicit?

Comment: This does not quite clarify it for me. What are the irreps and $P$ in this case then?